# Generate random image by url

Tags: html, image, random, request

I have an API with the endpoints:

- `api/image/1` Returns me the image 1
- `api/image/random` Gives me a random image

Whenever I make a call for a random image, like 5 times on one web page, each time it's the **same image**. It's a little bit like https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300...

I would like to have a random image, each time. Even if I call for a random image 10 times on one web page. Is there a way that this is possible?

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can see the calls to the API and the API code / documentation?

Comment: To edit this question with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/k7a4vctL/ The first 2 images will always be the same: is it possible to also make these really random in my API?

Comment: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As stated in this github [issue](https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-source-js/issues/9#issuecomment-239053606), you can basically use `https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=incrementingIdentifier`.

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=1" />
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=2" />
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=3" />
```

Answer (score 15):

They actually address this common issue in their documentation. Interestingly, you're using their recommendation to achieve the complete opposite:

> **Static Random Image**
> Get the same random image every time based on a seed, by adding /seed/{seed} to the start of the URL.

https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300

### Solution

According to Picsum, you could do:

> To request multiple images of the same size in your browser, add the random query param to prevent the images from being cached:
> `<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">`
> `<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2">`

Which results in:

[image]
[image]

Additionally, you can always get a list of URLs using their API, it allows you to define the number of images and many more things. I would suggest to actually read the small guide they put up [on their site](https://picsum.photos/)

Comment: this is better in my opinion

Answer (score 10):

API that's simple to use. It will redirect you to a random image every time.

**URL**

> https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200

**Syntax**

> `https://source.unsplash.com/random/<width>x<height>`

**Here is JS trick to get unique image on every request**

> `https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200?sig=${Math.random()}`

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by browser caching as your are effectively requesting the same image, this can be seen in this screen grab from my browser,

Two lines of code,

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
```

One server request,

[image]

Depending on what language you are using you will need to add some element of random to the url,

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?nocache=<?php echo microtime(); ?>" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?nocache=<?php echo microtime(); ?>">
```

I have added microtime() here in PHP, the use of microtime is significant as using time() will not always provide a different request url if the server and client are quick.

I now get two requests and two images,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to random the numbers in your url;
URL => https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1

```html
<img id = 'imgShow' />
```

```js
document.getElementById('imgShow').src = 'https://picsum.photos/'+(200+rand())+'/' + (300 + rand()) +'?random=1';}

function rand(){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * 90)} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In seeder/factory of Laravel(PHP) you can use something like:

```
'url' => 'https://picsum.photos/1024/1024?nocache='.microtime()
```